# Why I cant delete todo item in todo list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What should I do to remove item from my todo list? What did i do wrong?

Here is my code

```
function App1() {
  const myInputValue = useRef();
  const [todo, setToDo] = useState([]);
  const addItem = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const id = uuid();
    setToDo([
      ...todo,
      {
        id: id,
        name: myInputValue.current.value,
      },
    ]);
    myInputValue.current.value = "";
  };
  const removeItem = e => {
        const data = todo.filter(el => el.e !== e);
        setToDo(data);
  };
  const listItems = todo.map((element) => (
    <li key={element.id}>
      {element.name}
      <button>Done</button>
      <button onClick={() => removeItem(element.id)}>Delete</button>
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={myInputValue}></input>
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>
      <ul>
        {listItems}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App1;
```

What should I change in my removeItem function? Where I do a mistake? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iam not sure about it, but when you are adding an item, you add an object with these following keys (id and name), so why when you call removeItem, you test with elemnt.e; didn't you mean to write this ? :

```
todo.filter(el => el.id !== e)
```

instead of this:

```
todo.filter(el => el.e !== e)
```

Comment: omg....I`m so stupid....thx a lot, bro. May be It cause I want to sleep so much....

Comment: No Problem bro, when you are tired, take some rest, It happened to me to stay stuck with a semicolon forgoten within a PHP code because I was half asleep x)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const removeItem = e => {  //e is your id so you compare with other obj ids 
    const data = todo.filter(el => el.id !== e); 
    setToDo(data);
```

};

Comment: Yeh, I`m already inderstood this, thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the element's name instead of the element itself.

```
<button onClick={() => removeItem(element.name)}>Delete</button>
```

Maybe it was better if you to compare the todo's id in your filter function. Try change your removeItem function to be like this.

```
const removeItem = e => {
        const data = todo.filter(el => el.id !== e.id);
        setToDo(data);
  };
```